# UIStackView not resizing its width inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have to display multiple views inside a single view controller. I have added a scroll view and added the views through the interface builder. Constraints added to all four sides as well.

[image]

Each label (green label) and view (gray view) is embedded in a `UIStackView`. I have set the leading, top, trailing and height constraints added to each stack view. No auto layout issues/warnings in Xcode.

But when I run the app, it shows up like this.

[image]

Why doesn't the stackview get the width according to the leading and trailing constraints I've set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add three more constraints.

1. Pin width of A Stack View equal to superview -16.
2. Pin width of B = width of A
3. Pin width of C = width of B

[image]